# JUnit output in Maven reports

Tags: java, logging, maven-2, junit, report

I am using Maven for my project and have following question:

I want to see the logging output of my JUnit tests (log4j, System.out, whatever) in test reports. Do you have any idea how to achieve this?

Thanks ;-)

Comment: how are you running your maven build?

Comment: Just using command line: mvn test/install/package/etc.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

I believe you can redirect the output (`System.out`) of test using the maven surefire plugin configuration key **redirectTestOutputToFile**, and then find the output in `target/surefire-reports`

Check more about this in [the plugin docs](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#redirectTestOutputToFile)

In one snipplet:

```
<build>
  <plugins>
      <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
      <configuration>
          <redirectTestOutputToFile>true</redirectTestOutputToFile>
      </configuration>
      </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```