# Is it possible to disable log4j exception output during jUnit tests run?

Tags: maven, junit, log4j

Need to disable log4j output to console during jUnit tests running but all other log4j output should be enable. There are lot exceptions during testing while checking method reaction on incorrect argument, so exception is ok.

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2031354/2448440) for a `pom`-only solution

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Create a new log4j properties file called e.g. `log4j-test.properties` with logging disabled. In your surefire config in the POM, add `argLine` with `-Dlog4j.configuration=log4j-test.properties`.

Comment: Just to precise this answer: add this single line to the property file: log4j.rootLogger=OFF

Answer (score 7):

*I know this question is quite old, but still relevant in my opinion, so I'll add an alternative answer.*

If you just want to disable (or reduce) logging for certain tests, or for some reason want to do it from code rather than creating a config file, you could do the following:

```
RootLogger.getRootLogger().setLevel(Level.OFF);
```