# Do not display stacktrace of thrown exception messages in JUnit test

Tags: java, junit4

While testing for message value of thrown exception messages like this:

```
public void mustFailIfTheActionDoesNotExist() {
        try {
            getAction(UUID.randomUUID().toString());

            fail("Must fail if the action does not exists");
        } catch (MyException ex) {
            Assert.assertEquals("Exception generated on action", ex.getMessage());
        }
```

the exception and their stacktrace are visible on the terminal. As I have hundreds of classes in my project, the terminal just becomes a long list of stacktraces of exception messages.

Is there a way to suppress the stack-trace of exception output to screen/terminal when Junit tests are run?

PS: I don't want to suppress logging for all unit tests, just in specific cases.

Comment: You could close the output stream but you will need to reopen it at the end of this test case

Comment: This seems similar to what you say: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33871861/3285138. But I wish I could just disable stacktrace, as that is the one that mainly occupies the space.

Comment: Well, what are you using to log ? You can redirect the streams with `System.setOut(PrintStream)` and `System.setErr(PrintStream)`. Save those somewhere, then override them into a file (to keep tracks) or close them to hide everything. Then at the end, reset the saved instance into the System instance.

Comment: I am using log4j for logging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the following test you can test if the exception is thrown. But you can not have test(like fail) after exception is thrown. They will not be executed.Also, it will not print stacktrace.

```
@Test(expected = MyException.class)
public void mustFailIfTheActionDoesNotExist() throws MyException{
     getAction(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
     fail("Must fail if the action does not exists");
}
```

To be able to have tests after the exception is thrown. You can check out [ExpectedException Rule](http://baddotrobot.com/blog/2012/03/27/expecting-exception-with-junit-rule/index.html).

**Update:**

```
@Rule
public ExpectedException exception = ExpectedException.none();
@Test
public void shouldNotPrintStackTrace() throws ArithmeticException {
    exception.expect(ArithmeticException.class);
    exception.expectMessage(containsString("by zero"));
    System.out.println(10 / 0);
}
```

The above code doesnot show stacktrace in case of success, and you can test the message. In case of test failure it prints stacktrace.

Comment: This won't let me test the exception message. The ExpectedException lets me do that, but also prints stack-trace.

Comment: @goelakash please see my updated answer. Could you share your code with ExpectedException then we could see what does not work.

Answer (score 6):

I'm guessing that the code you are testing is logging an exception and throwing it. Don't do that.

When catching an exception in non-test code, do one of these:

1. Log the exception and move on
2. Rethrow the exception without logging it
3. Wrap the exception and throw the wrapped exception without doing any logging

If you do this, then any exception will get logged at most once.

You also should ensure that all exceptions are logged at the top level of your code. This may require calling `Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler()` or `Thread.setUncaughtExceptionHandler()