# Get result from junit test

Tags: java, testing, junit, automation, selenium-webdriver

I'm using selenium webdriver 2.0 java api to run some tests in my company. I'm doing it at free will and have no heavy knowledge about automation so part my ignorance.

I would like to know how can I retrieve the result from a "@test" method in case I would like to log results of tests to file.

Say I have this test case, how will I return a result for it as a boolean?

```
@Test
public void like(){

    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 5);


    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.className("feed-item-ph")));  

    WebElement like = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a.action-block-a.action-like"));
    like.click();

    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("registration-book")));

    driver.quit();

}
```

Comment: Every single tool that's capable of running JUnit tests is also capable of saving the test results in a file. What are you using? Ant, Maven? Do you have an IDE?

Comment: Using Eclipse with Maven

Comment: Then you could use the surefire maven plugin. Here's a related [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2030266/junit-output-in-maven-reports)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you can't. Either it is a Testcase, or it is a regular function. Since the Testdriver decides how to call your test case and it doesn't know what to do with the boolean anyway, this doesn't make any sense.

The most simple way to make it work, would be to write a function that returns a boolean and just to call that function inside a testcase. Then you can easily gether all the information you want.

Comment: Thank you, Can I call and run individual tests from a regular java class?

Comment: sure you can. But the nice thing about the annotated classes is, that you don't have to care about things like that anymore. So be sure that you don't give up a lot of freedom by not using the automatic tests. You can call the test methods just like any other method.

Comment: The problem is that all of the tests with selenium and junit are performed under one class and once I'll have 300 tests it will become ugly code. I would like to put them in different classes of tests and call the different tests under my control (# of tests to run and which order) and also be easier to maintain in time.