# How do I assign JUnit output to a String?

Tags: java, maven, logging, junit, java-6

I want to create bugs reports in my issue tracking software when unit tests fail. This means I need to save what normally is printed to my IDE's console when a test fails as a String. Thus far, I have the following code:

```
@Rule
public ErrorCollector collector = new ErrorCollector();
...

@Test
public void testFailedUnitTest() {
    collector.checkThat(3, equalTo(5));
}
```

It outputs the following to the console. I want to put this into a String instead of/in addition to outputting it to my IDE's console:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expected: <5>
     but: was <3>
    at org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat(MatcherAssert.java:20)
    at org.junit.Assert.assertThat(Assert.java:865)
    ...
```

I have tried:

1. Surrounding it with try/catch blocks and using e.get... but
   it didn't catch the java.lang.AssertionError. The code in the catch block wasn't even executed. I think that's because
   my collector is waiting to throw the exception after
   testFailedUnitTest() *completes* to throw the error so that it can
   continue executing a test that fails.
2. Surrounding a normal, non-collector JUnit test with try/catch blocks.
3. Grabbing the output in my tearDown(), after all the tests have
   completed. But there is no method like public String[]
   getJUnitFailures() in [the ErrorCollector JavaDoc](http://junit.org/javadoc/4.11/org/junit/rules/ErrorCollector.html) so
   that didn't work.
4. Various ways involving editing something in my pom.xml such as [setting the redirectTestOutputToFile element to true](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2031354/2167210)  but they have the same problems as 2), and unfortunately some legacy code doesn't use Maven. However, Maven-specific methods would be acceptable.

I spoke with someone in person who said that I *might* be able to log each test's output to a file using [the Logger class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/logging/Logger.html) and read each file in as a String. He admitted that that's a sloppy hack and could interfere with our other logging facilities.

Would that even work and if so, is it the best way to do it?

Thank you in advance. :)

Comment: Also I'm using JUnit 4.11 but I could easily change the version in my pom.xml if the solution is version-specific.

Comment: your requirement is wierd. best option would be to redirect all your console output to a log file. you may use log4j for that and also you should be able to fetch the correct log data which got logged from your junit as other logs would also be there. for that you should modify your appender in log4j.properties file with some string using which you could search.

Comment: This probably wouldn't work. You're recreating the wheel a bit here - I'd recommend you use an existing test framework that generates documentation, perhaps Sonar?

Comment: @EvanKnowles your comment is outside the scope of my question. I am trying to assign failed JUnit stacktraces to Strings so that I can automatically create issues in Jira, not autogenerate documentation.

Comment: Ah, I see. I feel that it would still be easier to use a tool such as Sonar, then use the XML that it generates as part of its results to create your Jira issues.

Comment: I am trying to avoid parsing XML or text files. But if I have to, I want to do it with the simplest possible techniques. Using a documentation generation framework to generate the XML file is overly complex. Can you please delete your comment since it pushes down future answers that don't involve logging or use simpler logging facilities?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a [TestWatcher](http://junit.org/javadoc/4.9/org/junit/rules/TestWatcher.html) can do what you want.

---

## Example

```
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.StringWriter;

import org.junit.Rule;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.rules.TestRule;
import org.junit.rules.TestWatcher;
import org.junit.runner.Description;

public class FailedTestCapturer {

  @SuppressWarnings("null")
  private static int throwNPE() {
    String x = null;
    return x.length();
  }

  private String exception;
  @Rule
  public final TestRule watchman = new TestWatcher() {
    @Override
    protected void failed(Throwable e, Description description) {
      StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
      e.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(writer));
      exception = writer.toString();
      System.out.println("Captured exception! --> " + exception);
    }
  };

  @Test
  public void failingTest() {
    throwNPE();
  }
}
```

## Output

```
Captured exception! --> java.lang.NullPointerException
    at FailedTestCapturer.throwNPE(FailedTestCapturer.java:15)
    at FailedTestCapturer.failingTest(FailedTestCapturer.java:32)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.rules.TestWatcher$1.evaluate(TestWatcher.java:55)
    at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```